# Stackdriver-trace on Google Cloud Run failing, while working fine on localhost

Tags: node.js, trace, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-run

I have a node server running on Google Cloud Run. Now I want to enable stackdriver tracing. When I run the service locally, I am able to get the traces in the GCP. However, when I run the service as Google Cloud Run, I am getting an an error:

```
"@google-cloud/trace-agent ERROR TraceWriter#publish: Received error with status code 403 while publishing traces to cloudtrace.googleapis.com: Error: The request is missing a valid API key."
```

I made sure that the service account has tracing agent role.

First line in my app.js

```
require('@google-cloud/trace-agent').start();
```

running locally I am using .env file containing

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path to credentials.json>
```

According to https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs `These values are auto-detected if the application is running on Google Cloud Platform` so, I don't have this credentials on the gcp image

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong.  Perhaps augment your question with the description of how you setup your Cloud Run service and maybe provide a trivial sample that we could use to test/recreate?

Comment: What is the identity of your Cloud Run and what are the roles on this identity?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am using default service account, but added cloud tracing agent role to it.
When I was using my service this morning again, everything seems to work fine. So, I think I can close the issue, but I am just wondering, does it take time before a service uses new roles that are assigned to it's account?

Comment: It's most of time very quick, but it can take up to 5 minutes (maximum that I have observed). I never experiment more, but it's not impossible!

Answer (score 1):

There are two challenges to using this library with Cloud Run:

1. Despite the note about auto-detection, Cloud Run is an exception. It is not yet autodetected. **This can be addressed for now with some explicit configuration.**
2. Because Cloud Run services only have resources until they respond to a request, queued up trace data may not be sent before CPU resources are withdrawn. **This can be addressed for now by configuring the trace agent to flush ASAP**

```js
const tracer = require('@google-cloud/trace-agent').start({
  serviceContext: {
    service: process.env.K_SERVICE || "unknown-service",
    version: process.env.K_REVISION || "unknown-revision"
  },
  flushDelaySeconds: 1,
});
```

On a quick review I couldn't see how to trigger the trace flush, but the shorter timeout should help avoid some delays in seeing the trace data appear in Stackdriver.

EDIT: While nice in theory, in practice there's still significant race conditions with CPU withdrawal. Filed https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-trace-nodejs/issues/1161 to see if we can find a more consistent solution.