# Stackdriver Trace PHP: How to send spans in the background?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-php

According to https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/php, App Engine flexible environment for PHP can run a daemon that sends trace spans to Stackdriver in the background rather than as part of the request processing (which could cause increased response latency).

I am running Kubernetes Engine, but would still like to send trace requests in the background. Therefore:

1. Is it possible to run that batch daemon myself?
2. Out of curiosity, how does the Stackdriver PHP Exporter pass these spans to the daemon? I tried to search for that in the source code, but could not find out how it is done.
3. If #1 is not possible, is there another way to perform span sending in the background?

[Stackdriver Trace with Google Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157906/stackdriver-trace-with-google-cloud-run) seems to cover a similar topic, but does not address how to run the daemon manually.

Comment: It looks like you can use Stackdriver Trace on GKE https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/, but keep in mind that it's in Alpha https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/php.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I know: this question refers specifically to sending trace spans in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking for this, I was able to run the batch daemon as follows:

`sudo -u www-data -E vendor/bin/google-cloud-batch daemon`

Note that the daemon itself *must* be run as the same user as your “serving” PHP processes in order to access SysV memory shared between both, hence the `sudo`.
You will also need the PHP sysv and pcntl extensions enabled.